# Асинхронное обновление состояния

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

JS-код сначала обновляет состояние, а затем отправляет запрос на сервер, чтобы обновить данные:

```
function onSubmit() {

 dispatch(addTodo(text, id)); //обновляем состояние

 fetch('http://localhost:5000/data/update', {   //запрос на сервер
  method: 'PATCH',
  headers: new Headers({
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }),
  body: JSON.stringify({username: login, todos})
 }).then(response => response.text())
   .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
   })
}
```

Но проблема в том, что состояние сразу не обновляется и нужно, чтобы программа подождала, пока строка dispatch выполнится и только потом отправляла запрос. Как это реализовать? Смотрю уроки по async, await, но не врубаюсь, как именно это сделать.

Comment: А вы пробовали `dispatch` писать внутри последнего `then`?

Comment: @EzioMercer, попробовал, на сервер отсылается всё равно необновлённое состояние

Comment: А, я не так понял, простите. Вам надо ваш второй `fetch` написать внутри `addTodo` и там после `then` вызывать ваш `fetch`

Comment: @EzioMercer, сработало, спасибо.